# AngularJS display total of field values of array within object

Tags: arrays, json, object

I am attempting to get the total of the field values of an array within on object and display it with a view using ng-repeat. How I'd like for it to look like with the JSON data below would be for each name, the total of the review rating values would be displayed. I am able to get the values of how many reviews per array, but I am also having trouble to display it.

Below is the JSON data I am using:

```
[{"_id":"56873fdb182b3741059357d1","longitude":123.76338959999998,
  "latitude":10.2594266,"location":"Cebu City","name":"Cebu City","__v":0,
  "category":"Attraction",
  "reviews":[
             {"comment":"This is a test. Changed to 3.5 stars.","rating":3.5,"userId":null,"review_id":"tiGCG2rGroIn"}
   ]}, 
 {"_id":"56873fc9182b3741059357d0","longitude":113.83507800000007,"latitude":22.1533884,"location":"Hong Kong","name":"Hong Kong","__v":0,"category":"Attraction",
  "reviews":[{"comment":"Add the comment to the form","rating":3.5,"userId":11,"review_id":"44NL7kkwhy72"},
             {"comment":"I'm not impressed by your performance. - GSP","rating":1.5,"userId":11,"review_id":"jN7f1iFlQVha"},
             {"comment":"Test","rating":2.5,"userId":11,"review_id":"QcJpw4yopF1q"}]}]
```

Angular Code

```
 .controller('HomeCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, LocFac) { 

 LocFac.getLocations().then(function successCallback(data)  {
   $scope.locations = data.data;     
   //for each location get a rating 
   $scope.loclen = ($scope.locations).length;  

   //for each repeat 
   var total = 0;
     for(var i = 0; i < $scope.loclen; i++){
        var loc = $scope.locations[i]; 
        //get amount of reviews for each location
        reviewlen = (loc.reviews).length;  

        locreviews = $scope.locations[i].reviews;

        //average the reviews for each location 
        ratings = locreviews; 
        total += (ratings.rating);   

        console.log(ratings);
     } 
  });  
})
```

Comment: Where would you like to display it? console only?

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado I'd like to display it on the view.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display object values on view, you should add it to the $scope.

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, LocFac) { 

 LocFac.getLocations().then(function successCallback(data)  {
   $scope.locations = data.data;     
   //for each location get a rating 
   $scope.loclen = ($scope.locations).length;  

   //for each repeat 
   var total = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < $scope.loclen; i++){
    var loc = $scope.locations[i]; 
    //get amount of reviews for each location
    var reviewlen = (loc.reviews).length;  

    $scope.locreviews = $scope.locations[i].reviews;

    //average the reviews for each location 
    $scope.ratings = locreviews; 
    $scope.total += (ratings.rating);   

    console.log(ratings);
     } 
  });  
})
```

Once you've done that, you can access it inside the view like this:

```
<label>{{ratings}}</label>
<label>{{total}}</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is simple.. Try this below code.

```
 $scope.data = [{
    "_id": "56873fdb182b3741059357d1",
    "longitude": 123.76338959999998,
    "latitude": 10.2594266,
    "location": "Cebu City",
    "name": "Cebu City",
    "__v": 0,
    "category": "Attraction",
    "reviews": [{
        "comment": "This is a test. Changed to 3.5 stars.",
        "rating": 3.5,
        "userId": null,
        "review_id": "tiGCG2rGroIn"
    }]
}, {
    "_id": "56873fc9182b3741059357d0",
    "longitude": 113.83507800000007,
    "latitude": 22.1533884,
    "location": "Hong Kong",
    "name": "Hong Kong",
    "__v": 0,
    "category": "Attraction",
    "reviews": [{
        "comment": "Add the comment to the form",
        "rating": 3.5,
        "userId": 11,
        "review_id": "44NL7kkwhy72"
    }, {
        "comment": "I'm not impressed by your performance. - GSP",
        "rating": 1.5,
        "userId": 11,
        "review_id": "jN7f1iFlQVha"
    }, {
        "comment": "Test",
        "rating": 2.5,
        "userId": 11,
        "review_id": "QcJpw4yopF1q"
    }]
}];
```

You have to loop this $scope.data by using ng-repeat. Example :

```
<div>

    <ul ng-repeat="location in data">
        <li ng-repeat="review in location.reviews">
            {{review.comment}}
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

I hope this helps.